# How do I add rotation on centre axis for a 3d object in sparkAR?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I want to rotate the 3d object on its axis,  currently I'm using sparkar built in ide rotation, which is basically making it move in a circle like manner, its not spinning on it axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this might help**

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/docs/3d-objects/

You can make 3D objects respond to other elements in your scene.
To do this, the 3D object should be a child of the element it should respond to